# Margin doesn't work properly in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have HTML code:

```css
h1{
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header col-md-7 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
  <h1><span class="title-pink">FIRST TITLE</span></h1>
  <h1><span class="title-pink">SECOND TITLE</span></h1>
  <h1><span class="title-pink">THIRD TITLE</span></h1>
</div>
```

On Chrome, this margin works properly, but when I open the website on IE 11, these margins don't appear at all. Why? Can you help me?

Comment: all margins do not work, or only the first and the last one? Do you get a margin between your h1 tags?

Comment: Are you using any kind of CSS reset to normalize your CSS across browsers? If not, it could be something like a difference in line-height between the two making them appear different.

Comment: Problem was with reset CSS, thank you @delinear

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet runs same on IE 11 and chrome, so style was applied correctly.
You used bootstrap, and it will override h1 style, so IE11 won't apply your style. On chrome, bootstrap may not be loaded because of CORS problem.
Overall, adding !important to style attributes will solve problem.

```
h1{
  margin-bottom: 2px !important;
  margin-top: 3px !important;
}
```